# What version of Xcode should i use to run my App on iPhone 3gs device 6.1.2 (10B146)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, version, osx-snow-leopard

I want to run my app on a device. I have iPhone 3GS version 6.1.2 (10B146). My current Xcode version is 4.0.2 and I am running Snow Leopard 10.6.6

Here is what Organizer telling me:

> The version of iOS on “iPhone” does not match any of the versions of
>   iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK.
>   Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or
>   update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is available here.
>
> OS Installed on iPhone
>   6.1.2 (10B146)
>
> Xcode Supported iOS Versions Latest
>   4.3,
>   4.2,
>   4.1,
>   4.0.2,

I read about that 4.2 is the last XCode version that supports Snow Leopard but I want to know does this version of Xcode support my device version? So I can be able to run my app on device. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Xcode 4.4+ and in order to do that you need to upgrade to Lion.

Comment: Nope, there isn't, at least not without a serious amount of hacking.  Even then, I don't think you will be allowed to submit it to the app store.

Comment: if yes than what version of ios should i downgrade? 4.3?

Comment: 4.3 is the maximum supported iOS version for that version of Xcode.  It is hard to downgrade iOS devices though.

Comment: Also you will not be able to support the large screen resolution of the iPhone 5 if you use any SDK lower then 6. For the iOS 6 SDK you will need Lion

Comment: ok thanks @borrrden i try to downgrade my phone instead update OSX and Xcode.. and hopefully it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should update your mac OS to Lion, and use xCode 4.6